# Database time conversion in Groovy

Tags: database, grails, groovy, timestamp

I'm getting `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ@c9a2424` kinda value when I'm trying to to get the timestamp from Oracle to my Groovy. I tried `stringValue()`, but didn't help me I got "String Convertion Failed" any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [dateValue](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMPTZ.html#dateValue_java_sql_Connection_):

> Calls toDate to convert internal Oracle TIMESTAMPTZ to a Java Date.

or [timeValue](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMPTZ.html#timeValue_java_sql_Connection_):

> Calls toTime to convert internal Oracle Date to a Java Time.

or [timestampValue](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/TIMESTAMPTZ.html#timestampValue_java_sql_Connection_):

> Calls toTimestamp to convert internal Oracle Date to a Java Timestamp.

or checkout other possibilities from **Method Summary** on that site.

Comment: I tried those. Didn't work, so I had posted a question. However I have fixed my issue by changing the response from DB to_char so now it's fine.